# foreach loop create a duplicated of last iteration

Tags: php, sql, foreach

So I have a php foreach loop which inserts however many images you upload in to a directory and creates a row in your DB for it. it works great except it is duplicating the last iteration.

I have tried doing an `array_splice` but that didn't work.

I know the query is subject to sql injections and will fix this once I get the iteration duplication sorted.

```
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = time().$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['userfile']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['userfile']['type'][$key];   
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }       
    $query="INSERT INTO table (user_id, filename) VALUES ('$user_id', '$file_name')";
    $desired_dir="/items/";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/items/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="/items/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
        mysql_query($query);            
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
echo "done";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

any ideas as to why its doing this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried dumping the contents of $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] to see if it contains a duplicate, or anything unexpected?

Comment: no I haven't tried that

Comment: give it a try.  It is possible you have a duplicate entry at the end of the array you would get the duplicate result you are seeing.

Comment: Inside the last "if.. else.." section you're calling $conn->query($query).  This will run whatever is in $query - in this case it will be the last value set inside your foreach loop.  That's what's causing you to duplicate the last entry.

Comment: @AlanHorrocks That did it thanks! i commented out the last section you mentioned, ran my code and it didn't duplicate the last iteration! thankyou!!

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer - so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the last *if.. else..* section you're calling *$conn->query($query)*. This will run whatever is in *$query* - in this case it will be the last value set inside your foreach loop. That's what's causing you to duplicate the last entry.